# iOS - AFNetworking crashing on line 577 of AFURLResponseSerialization.m

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking, lazy-loading

I'm implementing a lazy loading strategy in my app where I use `AFNetworking` to asynchronously load news article images in a `UITableView`. This is the following code that does that in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
@implementation PocketTableViewController

- (AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *)operationManager
{
    if (!_operationManager)
    {
        _operationManager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] init];
        _operationManager.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
    };

    return _operationManager;
} 

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    ...
    if (articleImageURL != nil) 
    {
        //set article image
        cell.ThumbImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyImage.png"];
        [cell.ThumbImage.associatedObject cancel];
        cell.ThumbImage.associatedObject =
        [self.operationManager GET:[articleImageURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                        parameters:nil
                           success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                               cell.ThumbImage.image = responseObject;
                           } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                               NSLog(@"Failed with error %@.", error);
                           }];
}
```

It works for most images when I scroll through the table view, but then it crashes here:

[image]

Any thoughts on why it's crashing?

UPDATE:

I found that it's crashing on this image url for some reason:

http://www.profitconfidential.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Bill-Gates-Bought-Stock-in-Third-Quarter.jpg

Comment: May be some special character may cause this error, try to encode the url using UTF8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I fixed the problem. There was nothing wrong with any of the images. I just had to disable all breakpoints in Xcode and it worked. Weird, but it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use UIImage+AFNetworking.
It lazy loading and supported image caching.

In your case, you can use this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:responseObject];
```

But  the best way is use UIImage+AFNetworking.

Comment: I've tried this before but ran into issues with table cell images being incorrectly assigned. I'm doing it my way because I followed this tutorial: http://cocoanuts.mobi/2014/04/27/fastscroll/ to solve the problem I was facing at the time.

Comment: try to remove responseSerializer and use imageWithData. Hope it help.